# Most Pythonic way to concatenate indented, wrapped paragraphs?

Tags: python

It seems that there would be a Pythonic way to loop over several paragraphs of wrapped and indented text, converting them into unindented text. That is, while looping over the following example input:

```
    abc def ghi
    jkl mno pqr

    stu vwx yz
```

turn it into:

```
abc def ghi
jkl mno pqr

stu vwx yz
```

The best I've come up with is the following:

```
for line in text:
    if line.strip() == '':
        string += '\n\n'
    else:
        string += line[3:]
```

which works, but seems woefully clumsy. Is there a way to avoid the if clause altogether? I've tried using [`textwrap.dedent()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent), but it seems to eliminate the paragraph breaks and run the words together at the newlines.

Comment: What is wrong with `"\n".join([line.strip() for line in text.splitlines()])`?

Comment: Why the special casing? Wouldn't `line[3:]` work even if `line` is empty? I think your problem is rather that you have trailing newlines, which you should definitely get rid of first

Comment: @thefourtheye Thats probably the best answer the OP is going to get. You should probably make it a bonafide answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @Niklas B The OP stated that he wanted the new lines left in the text and the tabs removed. What is wrong with ''.join(text.split('\t')) This will preserve the new lines as in the original and remove the tabs, treating the entire text as a single string

Comment: I see that you may have a number of spaces at the beginning of each line rather than a tab character. In that case just put the appropriate number of spaces in the split. As long as it is more than the number of spaces separating the individual character groups, it will work

Comment: @sabbahillel: One can just split the lines, then process the lines separately, then join them again.

Comment: @Niklas why bother to do that when it can be split and joined as a single text string. There is no need to process each line individually. One statement processes the entire text at once.

Comment: @sabbahillel you have to make sure you're stripping the spaces only from the start of the line, and not from the middle or anything. That is why you use `strip()` or `lstrip()`. Your method could break lines which include multiple spaces in them (not as an indent).

Comment: @thefourtheye: Absolutely nothing, that works perfectly and makes lots of sense. Just didn't think of it. Thank you!

Comment: @Kyle Barbour How about '\n'.join(text.strip('\t').split('\n\t')) where '\t' is used for the indent character. This preserves all indents that are within the text and not at the beginning of the line. It also prevents the strip from removing a space at the beginning that is not supposed to be part of the indent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text is an array:

```
 "\n".join(line.strip() for line in text)
```

If it's in a string:

```
 "\n".join(line.strip() for line in text.split("\n"))
```

It maintains all line breaks, including blank ones and the trailing newline.

```
>>> text="   asd dfk dfjk\n   jdfk dfkj dkfj\n\n  dfjk dfjk dfjk\n"
>>> print(text)
   asd dfk dfjk
   jdfk dfkj dkfj

  dfjk dfjk dfjk

>>> print("\n".join(line.strip() for line in text.split("\n")))
asd dfk dfjk
jdfk dfkj dkfj

dfjk dfjk dfjk

>>>
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks much! Only comment - isn't `text.splitlines()` preferable to `text.split("\n")`?

Comment: Yeah, probably. Perhaps `"".join(line.lstrip() for line in text.splitlines(True))` is cleaner as it uses universal newlines.

Comment: @icedtrees How about '\n'.join(text.strip('\t').split('\n\t')) where '\t' is used for the indent character. This preserves all indents that are within the text and not at the beginning of the line. It also prevents the strip from removing a space at the beginning that is not supposed to be part of the indent.